# Should I cancel coroutine in android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I started coroutine here to handle retrofit call without ViewModel directly in the activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_pass)

    job = Job()
    coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
}
```

retrofit call:

```
 private fun changePassCall(user: User) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
        var changePassDeferred = UserApiObj.retrofitServiceCoroutine.changePass(user, bearerToken)
        try {
            var response = changePassDeferred?.await()
            Toast.makeText(this@ChangePassActivity, "Pass changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

I cancel it here:

```
 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use lifecycleScope to launch a coroutine and you dont have to create a job or cancel it anymore.